# Class not found - JavaFX Native Packaging

Tags: java, javafx, native, packaging

I'm trying to deploy a program that I created but I'm having an error after the installation.
[image: Screenshot of installation]

I used Native Packaging to package it as an EXE installer and when I click said installer, it says the main class cannot be found. Here are some screenshots of the error:
[image: Class not found and JVM not launched error]

Why is it not finding the class?

Comment: The problem is probably when creating the package. What does happen if you execute the jar file that is included in the installation package `java -jar <path to jarfile>`.

Comment: @hotzst The jar file that was generated works fine and is running, sir. I don't why the .exe file created after clicking the generated installer isn't, tho.

Comment: @jessicajung I have the exact same problem. Did you, by any chance, manage to fix it?

Comment: I, too, am having this issue. Are you guys also trying to generate separate .exe runnables from the same project? I have a Client.exe and a Server.exe I am trying to create, all from the same code project. Maybe that is making Ant confused?

Comment: @jessicajung how did you fix this? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and after some deep dive research I found a workaround this bug in Deployment.  I think it has to do with how CSS and static fields are compiled along with the jfx app launch.  BTW I am not sure if it is fixed in later releases of jdk/jfx.
Problem manifests if you declare any FX object at all in your main JavaFX application class as global static in that class.  Then you can’t launch via the exe, regardless of the installer!  Else executing a jar via double click etc. is fine or java –jar foo.jar.
Workaround is a little ridiculous: (1) Don’t declare any static FX objects in your main application. (2) Put them anywhere else, even as an inner class!

Problem. This example will not exec via exe:

```
public class FooBarJavaXDDeploy extends Application {
    private static final Button btn = new Button(); // Problem
    public void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("Hello Btn World!");
        });
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    }
    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Goes through Main");
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Workaround:

```
public class FooBarJavaXDDeploy extends Application {
    static class INNER_STATIC_CLASS {
        static final Button btn = new Button();
    }

    public void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        INNER_STATIC_CLASS.btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        INNER_STATIC_CLASS.btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            System.out.println("Hello Btn World!");
        });
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(INNER_STATIC_CLASS.btn);
```

...
Workaround 2:

```
public class FooBarJavaXDDeploy extends Application {
    public void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not always the best method.
However, I had the same problem but it was solved.

First, if you are using kotlin,
Create a main class that will be the new entry point as a `Java` file.

The generated Java file should be as follows:

```
package {your_package};

import javafx.application.Application;

public class EP extends Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

The `Main` should be the class that seems to be the current entry point.
Perhaps the `Main` is defined as `open class Main: Application () {`.

Set the EP class generated this time as the entry point (main class).

If exe is generated as `-native image`,
Please try to execute the generated exe, paying attention to the following points.

○　Make sure the generated directory does not contain spaces or multibytes.

○　Do not execute directly from USB etc. (Copy to PC and execute)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue. I used maven and spring boot for the project. So after using maven to build the jar first then used org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher for the -appclass option. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, and for me it was simply that I was using mismatching versions of Java.  I was building a Jar using the Java 17 JDK and JavaFX 17, and trying to package it as an EXE using the Java 17 SDK as well.  However, I was using the Javapackager from the Java 8 SDK (the last Java version to include it).  I thought Javapackager was version-blind since it seemed to work just fine up until the part where I ran the EXE file.  But once I switched to doing everything with the Java 8 SDK, it immediately started working as expected.